# how to insert entities, which are already existing in db, into Icollection of a parent entity, and save changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext, savechanges

I'm a novice, so I guess in the code I'm about to present, ther're going to be lots of violations in terms of 'proper code'. (be glad to get any remark..)

I have three entites:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int AgeId { get; set; }
    ...//some properties
}

public class Age
{
    public int AgeId { get; set;}
    public int PersonsId { get; set; }

    ...//some properties

    public virtual ICollection<AgeRange> AgeRanges {get; set;}

}


public class AgeRange
{
    public string AgeRangeId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    ICollection<Age> Ages { get; set; }

}
```

I created a new 'Age' entity, set it's properies with values, then, insert to its 'Icollection' some 'AgeRange' entities, which I pull out of DB. (they already exist)
I add the new 'Age' to dbContex, and when perform 'savechanges' I get exception:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AgeRanges'. Cannot insert duplicate key in  object 'dbo.AgeRanges'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

(AgeRange PK is string on purpose, as my intention is to keep them constant on a logic basis)

here's the rest of the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddPerson(AddPersonViewModel vm)
 {

         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {   
             Services services = new Services();
             Age age = services.GetAgeEntity(vm.Ages); 
             db.Ages.Add(age);
             db.SaveChanges(); //exception apears here.
             ........

         }

public class Services
{
    ModelContext db;

    public Services()
    {
        db = new ModelContext();
    }

    public Age GetAgeEntity(string[] ages)
    {
        Age age = new Age();

        //some more code...

        age.AgeRanges = GetAgeRanges(ages);   
        return age;
    }

        }



    ICollection<AgeRange> GetAgeRanges(string[] ages)
    {
        Age age = new Age();
        age.AgeRanges = new List<AgeRange>();

        foreach (string item in ages)
        {
            var ageRange = db.AgeRanges.Find(item);
            age.AgeRanges.Add(ageRange);
        }

        return age.AgeRanges;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having this error because you are using two different contexts: One the read the `AgeRange` entities from the database: It's the `ModelContext db` private member in your `Services` class which you create in the constructor:

```
db = new ModelContext();
```

And a second context to add the `Age` entity together with the `AgeRange` collection you are using in the controller action:

```
db.Ages.Add(age);
```

This cannot be the same `db` instance. The second context does not know anything about the `AgeRange` entities because they have been loaded in another context. Hence `SaveChanges` tries to insert them as new entities.

You could create two additional methods in your `Services` class:

```
public void AddAgeEntity(Age age)
{
    db.Ages.Add(age);
}

public void SaveChanges()
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

And in your controller:

```
Services services = new Services();
Age age = services.GetAgeEntity(vm.Ages); 
services.AddAgeEntity(age);
services.SaveChanges();
```

Now the whole operation uses the same context and your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Repositories with Autofac to automatically create instances of you Services and/or repositories, then you should register the context like this

`builder.RegisterInstance<IMyContext>(new MyContext("MyContext"));`

This will register the context as a single isntance; so with this you will allways bean using the same context in all your Services or Repositories.